# How to have an uninstaller along with launcher of my flex application

Tags: apache-flex, air

When I create a native installer and run it, it installs the application with myApp.exe (launcher) in my Program Files/myApp/ folder. I would also like to have the installer put an uninstaller for my application (say uninstall_myApp.exe or something) in the same folder. Is there any way to create such an installer. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If you run the installer or the AIR application twice, it will give you the option to uninstall que application. The installer is also the uninstaller.

You can call it that (install/uninstall) and then this will be clear to the user.

Maria